# Can't work out the indexOutOfBounds error I am getting

Tags: java

I am trying to create a deal method for dealing a deck of cards.

```
   import java.util.List;
   import java.util.ArrayList;

    /**
     * The Deck class represents a shuffled deck of cards.
     * It provides several operations including
     *      initialize, shuffle, deal, and check if empty.
     */
    public class Deck {

        /**
         * cards contains all the cards in the deck.
         */
        private List<Card> cards;

        /**
         * size is the number of not-yet-dealt cards.
         * Cards are dealt from the top (highest index) down.
         * The next card to be dealt is at size - 1.
         */
        private int size;


        /**
         * Creates a new <code>Deck</code> instance.<BR>
         * It pairs each element of ranks with each element of suits,
         * and produces one of the corresponding card.
         * @param ranks is an array containing all of the card ranks.
         * @param suits is an array containing all of the card suits.
         * @param values is an array containing all of the card point values.
         */
        public Deck(String[] ranks, String[] suits, int[] values) {
            /* *** TO BE IMPLEMENTED IN ACTIVITY 2 *** */

                    cards = new ArrayList<Card>();

                    int n = 0; 
                    for(int i = 0; i < ranks.length - 1; i++)
                        for(int j = 0; j < suits.length - 1; j++)
                            for(int k = 0; k < values.length - 1; k++)
                            {
                                if(n < cards.size())
                                    cards.add(n + 1, new Card(ranks[i],
                                              suits[j], values[k]));   
                            }

                    this.size =  52 - cards.size(); 
                    shuffle(); 
        }


        /**
         * Determines if this deck is empty (no undealt cards).
         * @return true if this deck is empty, false otherwise.
         */
        public boolean isEmpty() {
            /* *** TO BE IMPLEMENTED IN ACTIVITY 2 *** */
                    if(size() == 0)
                        return true;
                    else 
                        return false; 
        }

        /**
         * Accesses the number of undealt cards in this deck.
         * @return the number of undealt cards in this deck.
         */
        public int size() {
            /* *** TO BE IMPLEMENTED IN ACTIVITY 2 *** */
                    return this.size;// the number of undealt cards in the deck 

        }

        /**
         * Randomly permute the given collection of cards
         * and reset the size to represent the entire deck.
         */
        public void shuffle() {
            /* *** TO BE IMPLEMENTED IN ACTIVITY 4 *** */
        }

        /**
         * Deals a card from this deck.
         * @return the card just dealt, or null if all the cards have been
         *         previously dealt.
         */
        public Card deal() {
            /* *** TO BE IMPLEMENTED IN ACTIVITY 2 *** */
                    if(isEmpty())
                        return null; 
                    else
                    {
                        this.size++;
                        return cards.get(size - 1); 
                    } 
        }

        /**
         * Generates and returns a string representation of this deck.
         * @return a string representation of this deck.
         */
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            String rtn = "size = " + size + "\nUndealt cards: \n";

            for (int k = size - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
                rtn = rtn + cards.get(k);
                if (k != 0) {
                    rtn = rtn + ", ";
                }
                if ((size - k) % 2 == 0) {
                    // Insert carriage returns so entire deck is visible on console.
                    rtn = rtn + "\n";
                }
            }

            rtn = rtn + "\nDealt cards: \n";
            for (int k = cards.size() - 1; k >= size; k--) {
                rtn = rtn + cards.get(k);
                if (k != size) {
                    rtn = rtn + ", ";
                }
                if ((k - cards.size()) % 2 == 0) {
                    // Insert carriage returns so entire deck is visible on console.
                    rtn = rtn + "\n";
                }
            }

            rtn = rtn + "\n";
            return rtn;
        }
    ----------

    }
```

Comment: and? what's the issue, exactly?

Comment: 1) There is no question here 2) Post your stack trace 3) What line is it on?

Comment: please provide an error message

Comment: The most suspicious line is the one where a new card is tried to be added to index 1 on an empty list… It is in the constructor: `if(n < cards.size())
                                    cards.add(n + 1, new Card(ranks[i],
                                              suits[j], values[k]));` n and cards.size() are 0, and afterwards the new card is added to index n + 1, will not work! IndexOutOfBounds...

Answer (score 1):

```
else
    {
        this.size++;
        return cards.get(size - 1); 
    }
```

Look suspicious for me. It seems as you're trying to access `nth` element of `n-size` array.

Once you have a size, you can't just increment it without adding new element to the list.

Comment: Weird that we both said "Looks suspicious" independently...

Comment: @Michael It's wired in deed :) I didn't see your answer - thought I answer first :p Look that we suggest different places in code.

Comment: OP's code is obviously just very suspicious :)

Answer (score 0):

This line looks suspicious to me:

```
this.size =  52 - cards.size();
```

By your own Javadoc:

> size is the number of not-yet-dealt cards

So say after the for loop, you have 52 cards in the `List`. Your size is set to `52 - 52 = 0`, which means there are zero undealt cards, or rather all of the cards are dealt before even doing anything.

`this.size` should be initialised to just:

```
this.size = cards.size();
```

I also suggest renaming this because it's not very descriptive, but that may be outside of what you're "allowed" to do* (it looks at if you're filling in skeleton code). I would call it this:

```
private int cardsRemaining;
```

Because this value is the number of **not yet dealt** cards, you need to decrement when you deal. The number of *dealt* has gone *up*, the number of *undealt* cards has gone *down*.

```
public Card deal() {
    if(isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    } 
    else
    {
        this.size--;
        return cards.get(size - 1); 
    } 
}
```

---

<sub>* and as everyone knows, educators' code is always 100% flawless and can not be questioned or improved under any circumstances!</sub>